# spawning cmd.exe error in vs2008

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

I have created a simple vc++ console application and try to print "Hello World".  I am using Windows Server 2003 machine.

When I try to build this project I got the error as **Error: spawning cmd.exe**

How do I fix this?

Comment: when you compile or when you Run/Debug it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes i hav found where the proble.
I unable to locate path of cmd.exe
so
go to visualstudio tools->options->projects and  ->vc++ directories and specify ($SystemRoot)/system32 then it working fine.

Comment: Good. Hope the answers given in this page helped you.

Answer (score 16):

Check if cmd.exe is in `<Path>` environment variable?

I just did a small test by removing the `%SystemRoot%\system32` from `path` environment variable and I got the same problem what you are facing.

> Error 4   Error spawning
>   'cmd.exe'.    Project SEH

If it is the path issue then try adding below to `Projects and Solutions -> VC++ Directories`:

> $(SystemRoot)\System32

Answer (score 3):

If you get error like this

Just open *Tools –> Options –> Projects and Solutions –> VC++ Directories*

and add these lines :

1. `$(SystemRoot)\System32`
2. `$(SystemRoot)`
3. `$(SystemRoot)\System32\wbem`

Answer (score 1):

http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2005/09/12/cmdspawnerror

Answer (score 0):

Are you running on Vista? Could this be a case of needing to run Visual Studio as Administrator?

Answer (score 0):

I believe cmd.exe is not runnable by a non administrative user by default on Windows Server 2003, so I would check its permissions.  That of course assumes you are not running it as Administrator already.

Answer (score 0):

Yep. (Another weird windows error)
Projects and Solutions -> VC++ Directories -> Executable Files
Add $(SystemRoot)\System32 
it works

Answer (score 0):

It was giving error for me because **cmd.exe** was not accessible with the current user.
What I did to solve this problem :

> 1. Close current Visual Studio.
> 2. Reopen Visual Studio by right clicking on visual studio and select 'Run as administrator'
> 3. Now run The project.

**Why It works**

To access cmd.exe application must have privilege to run this. It doesn't have permission to access this and hence it works next time when you tries to access it normally(without running application as Administrator)

**Operating System**
Windows 7